# Transferring incoming data with websocket

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, websocket

The data below comes from the websocket. How can I import this incoming data into the textBox?

Let me summarize briefly.
When the form is opened, it connects to the socket server, then receives the data "Visual studio shows it on the output screen".
But this incoming data needs to be thrown into the textbox.

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new Client("AVk6BBXiZfE_m5", "RPeNkWb55RhvrcbWAwvj3LEBgzJzK");
    var api = new FtxRestApi(client);
    var wsApi = new FtxWebSocketApi("wss://ftx.com/ws/");

    await WebSocketTests(wsApi, client);
}

public async Task WebSocketTests(FtxWebSocketApi wsApi, Client client)
{
    var ins = "ETC-PERP";

    wsApi.OnWebSocketConnect += () =>
    {
        wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSockerRequestGenerator.GetAuthRequest(client));
        wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSockerRequestGenerator.GetSubscribeRequest("orderbook", ins));
        //  wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSockerRequestGenerator.GetSubscribeRequest("trades", ins));
        //  wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSockerRequestGenerator.GetSubscribeRequest("ticker", ins));
        //  wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSockerRequestGenerator.GetSubscribeRequest("fills"));
        //  wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSockerRequestGenerator.GetSubscribeRequest("orders"));
    };

    textBox.text = data?;

    await Task.Run(async () => await wsApi.Connect());
}
```

Comment: Are you catch a cross-thread operation not valid exception?

Comment: can you help me ? I need to import the incoming data into the textBox